# macOS Catalina hibernatemode 25 invalid?

Tags: macos, catalina, sleep-wake, hibernate

(MacBook Pro 13" 2020 w/ macOS 10.15.5)

I've always set hibernatemode to 25 for all my old Mac's (running OS 10.10.5) without a problem. However, setting hibernatemode to 25 on Catalina didn't seem to work, even when I turned off the Standby feature as suggested in this link: [macOS Mojave hibernatemode 25 | Dark Wake/ sleep wake](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352504/macos-mojave-hibernatemode-25-dark-wake-sleep-wake) .
Whenever I open the lid, I see the login screen immediately; apparently it did not wake from a hibernation state. I checked the "Wake from" Console history and it showed several "Wake from Deep Idle" events; none of them was "Wake from Hibernate".

Is it possible to make Catalina hibernate?

Comment: Exact same issue here, but I've been unable to find a fix so far. Seems to be a bug in Catalina.

Comment: Is the `powernap` setting on or off? I'm not certain how powernap interacts with hibernate. Keep in mind, however, that modern systems expect a SSD drive, and try to minimize disk-writes (to preserve your drive as long as possible). True hibernate mode could impact the life of your drive.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but still relevant as some people use old Macs even today.

I can confirm that on my MacBook Pro mid-2012 (non-Retina) a real hibernate mode no longer works in Catalina. After opening the lid there is virtually no delay until the screen is visible; moreover, while in its sleep state, the LED does not turn off but keeps on pulsing.

I currently have 3 systems on that same MacBook:

1. El Capitán
   `hibernatemode 25`: real hibernation happens, LED turns off; when waking up, the machine sound can be heard and the progress bar appears
2. Mojave
   `hibernatemode 25`: LED turning off; when waking up, machine sound; no progress bar, though
3. Catalina
   `hibernatemode 25`: screen gets dark, but LED keeps on pulsing; waking up: no machine sound, the screen is immediately visible

According to some statement by an Apple technician (mentioned in a few forums) `hibernatemode 25` is still in the macOS code but no longer gets applied. So this mode seems to be invalid, indeed.

By the way, I really tried everything (PRAM reset, SMC reset, all kinds of `pmset` settings, etc.), but nothing helped.

Comment: I seem to remember that it was a 'legacy' mode for laptops about a decade ago, or more.